# Android FullScreen theme reduces height of displayed Button

Tags: android, button, styles, height, themes

I've a **login** activity with two button, one is mine, another is from Facebook SDK.
I can see the Button with id "auth" equal to the facebook button in width and height.
If in the manifest I set

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

to have the activity in full screen, I've a strange result: the height of my Button is reduce, so I see a mashed rectangle.

This is the code of login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
android:fillViewport="true" >


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <!-- Logo Start -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_claim" />
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/auth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Login" />  


    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        android:padding="10dip" >

        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            facebook:login_text="Login with Facebook" />

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:visibility="gone" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make activity fullscreen by java code instead of xml:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FUL  LSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: layout_width property depending on parent layout:
but in your case may be facebook buttons are not conform Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen style, and when you use programatically full screen it not apply this style that not conform fullscreen style...